# How to convert Standard time to military time using Formula filed?

Tags: formula

I want to convert to standard time to military time. For example if time is 07:00 PM then it converted in military time such as 1900.

Any help will really helpful for me.

Comment: You can do it by make it as number and addin 1200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TEXT(FLOOR (MOD( Date_Time_Field_Goes_Here__c - ($System.OriginDateTime + 5/24),1) *24))+ LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT( Date_Time_Field_Goes_Here__c ),6),2)
```

In the above example, the 5/24 represents the time zone the user is in. In the example, the user is in EST or GMT-5 so we use 5/24. In order to display an accurate time to the user this value needs to be changed to reflect the hours away from GMT the user is in.

Example: 6/24 is CST, 7/24 is MST, and 8/24 is PST.

Comment: If i use this formula it comvert 6:55 AM to 655 but i need 0655.